# How can I print or get a specific value on an associative array (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative-array

I have an array that returns keys and values.

```
 <?php

 print_r(array_values($arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"])); 
 $arresults = $arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"];

  ?>
```

The code above would show this result:

```
    Array ([0] => Array 
       ([ID] => 29 
       [TIMESTAMP_X] => 2014-08-26 08:23:13 
       [IBLOCK_ID] => 3 
       [NAME] => ProductID 
       [ACTIVE] => Y 
       [SORT ] => 500 
       [CODE] => product_id 
       [DEFAULT_VALUE] => 
       [PROPERTY_TYPE] => S 
       [ROW_COUNT] => 1 
       [COL_COUNT] => 30 
       [LIST_TYPE] => L 
       [MULTIPLE] => N 
       [XML_ID] => [file_type] => 
       [MULTIPLE_CNT] => 5 
       [TMP_ID] => 
       [LINK_IBLOCK_ID] => 0 
       [WITH_DESCRIPTION] => N 
       [SEARCHABLE] => N 
       [filtrable] => N 
       [IS_REQUIRED] => N 
       [VERSION] = > 1 
       [user_type] =>  
       [USER_TYPE_SETTINGS] => 
       [HINT] => 
       [PROPERTY_VALUE_ID] => 11880 
       [VALUE] => PCA.CD08.21.A1 
       [DESCRIPTION] => 
       [VALUE_ENUM] => 
       [VALUE_XML_ID] => 
       [VALUE_SORT] => 
       [~ VALUE] => PCA.CD08.21.A1 
       [~ DESCRIPTION] => 
       [~ NAME] => ProductID 
       [~ DEFAULT_VALUE] => 
       [display_value] => PCA.CD08.21.A1) 
    )
```

**Problem:** How can I show the value **PCA.CD08.21.A1** .. What php code do i use to display only **PCA.CD08.21.A1** ?

Kindly Please Help Me...

Comment: What does the following pring?  print_r($arResult['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']); because array_values removes the key

Comment: @vizvi About to do the same thing... Redshot, please format your question so that it is easy to read and makes it easy for folks to answer it - it's only in your interest to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply access the value directly:

```
echo $arResult['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES'][0]['VALUE'];
```

However, you have to replace index `0` with the proper index, since calling `array_values()` on `$arResult` will numerically reindex it.

Comment: Same here, the 0 index is a result of the array_values method, it's nicer and better to access it by the right key

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
$display_value = $arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"][0]["display_value"]
```

Keeping in mind that we do not know what the first key in the array is you can do the following:

```
$arr = array_shift($arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]);
$display_value = $arr["display_value"];
```

Comment: The 0 index is a result of array_values, so he shouldn't even use the array_values method and access it by name

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] as $key => $value)
{
if($key == 'VALUE')
   echo $value;
}
```